# Return sum of array using pointer - no output

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am writing a function to return the sum of an array, but my test cases show that there is no output from that particular function. Anyone can help?

```
double sumArray(int n, double * array) {
    // Add your code here
    int i; 
    double sum = 0.000000;
    double *ptr;
    ptr = array;
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0.000000;
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum = sum + *ptr;
            ptr++;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you supposed to see output?

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8Y18UimLE3e0TmCW). Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with desired behavior.

Comment: This is function is not supposed to print anything, we are given test cases and it shows no output from this function.

Comment: What does "shows no output from this function" mean? This function does not output anything so of course there is "no output from this function". Please post an MCVE as requested.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little cleaner, more readable (imo), and safer.

```
double sumArray(const double * const arr, size_t n) {
    // promise the compiler that you won't change anything in the array or the pointer itself
    // the size of an array should always be >= 0, so use a size_t
    double sum = 0.0;
    const double *ptr = arr; // create a const pointer and point it at the array
    size_t i; // counter variable
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) // iterate up to n
        sum += *ptr++; // dereference ptr and increment it
    return sum;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double arr[] = { 1.0, 1.5, 2.1 };
    printf("%f\n", sumArray(arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(double)));
    return 0;
}
```